pip install 'tensorflow[and-cuda]' on Fedora 40
I tried to install tensorflow and CUDA together by python3 -m pip install 'tensorflow[and-cuda]', but it seems that something went wrong. Unfortunately, I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I seems to be related to protobuf, but how can I fix it? My OS is Fedora40 Scientific.
Here is the output
Installing collected packages: namex, libclang, flatbuffers, wheel, werkzeug, termcolor, tensorboard-data-server, protobuf, optree, opt-einsum, nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12, nvidia-nccl-cu12, nvidia-curand-cu12, nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12, nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12, nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12, nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12, nvidia-cublas-cu12, ml-dtypes, mdurl, markdown, h5py, google-pasta, gast, absl-py, tensorboard, nvidia-cusparse-cu12, nvidia-cufft-cu12, nvidia-cudnn-cu12, markdown-it-py, astunparse, rich, nvidia-cusolver-cu12, keras, tensorflow
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
googleapis-common-protos 1.63.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0.dev0,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 5.29.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed absl-py-2.1.0 astunparse-1.6.3 flatbuffers-24.3.25 gast-0.6.0 google-pasta-0.2.0 h5py-3.12.1 keras-3.7.0 libclang-18.1.1 markdown-3.7 markdown-it-py-3.0.0 mdurl-0.1.2 ml-dtypes-0.4.1 namex-0.0.8 nvidia-cublas-cu12-12.5.3.2 nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12-12.5.82 nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12-12.5.82 nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12-12.5.82 nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12-12.5.82 nvidia-cudnn-cu12-9.3.0.75 nvidia-cufft-cu12-11.2.3.61 nvidia-curand-cu12-10.3.6.82 nvidia-cusolver-cu12-11.6.3.83 nvidia-cusparse-cu12-12.5.1.3 nvidia-nccl-cu12-2.21.5 nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12-12.5.82 opt-einsum-3.4.0 optree-0.13.1 protobuf-5.29.1 rich-13.9.4 tensorboard-2.18.0 tensorboard-data-server-0.7.2 tensorflow-2.18.0 termcolor-2.5.0 werkzeug-3.1.3 wheel-0.45.1

It's so easy to overlook the error message.
"This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. googleapis-common-protos 1.63.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0.dev0,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 5.29.1 which is incompatible"
This tells you that you have to downgrade protobuf to 3.19.5 from your currently installed 5.29.1.
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install protobuf==3.19.5
python3 -m pip install 'tensorflow[and-cuda]'

